# How to reduce "Files" 0.3.2 window size?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, window-management, pantheon

Before updating the size of the file manager windows might be smaller.
The problem is more visible on the other skins, e.g. Arc Theme.
It is a way to remove this restriction?

Screenshot presents the pasted image with the previous smallest window size[image].

Comment: It seems that the minimal window size depends from the theme used indeed: with the "elementary" default theme you can have smaller windows as with the "Arc" styles. You might consider filing a bug, I am not sure if it's not intended, though.

Comment: I tested several skins and the problem is with the Arc theme. Other skins are acceptable window size.

Answer (score 3):

The minimum window size  (910 x 640 in pixels) is now hard coded into Files as the result of a recent merge, so cannot be changed (except with a bug request, possibly).  It was thought to be a reasonable minimum usable size and on my computer occupies less than one quarter of the screen (on Loki with elementary theme). If the window is appearing bigger with a different theme then something else is stopping it shrinking e.g. widgets taking more room - so reducing the absolute minimum, or making it a setting may not help.